# Why do Fiber Powders (to relieve Constipation) Emphasize Soluble Fiber rather than Insoluble Fiber

Tags: fibre, constipation

Why do Fiber Powders such as Konsyl, Benefiber, etc list Fiber (usually 5 g per serving), followed by Soluble Fiber (usually 3 to 5 g per serving)

According to [WebMd](https://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/dietary-fiber-the-natural-solution-for-constipation#1) insoluble fibers are better for constipation than soluble fibers

[Livestrong](https://www.livestrong.com/article/18528-foods-prevent-constipation/) lists foods to prevent constipation, all of them are insoluble fiber.

I would think that Fiber Powders (to relieve constipation) emphasize insoluble fiber content.

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use insoluble fibers you're just adding to the bulk of your meal.  Soluble fibers mean that they can be dissolved ( soluble ) which can then be taken as a drink.  And as they pass through the colon they absorb more water increasing the stool bulk.

And of course we advise people to increase their insoluble fiber intake, but that's usually in the form of food.

https://www.webmd.com/diet/features/insoluble-soluble-fiber

Comment: Insoluble fiber absorbs water and is not fermented, which is how it adds bulk to the stool. Soluble fiber is more or less fermented to short-chain fatty acids and other nutrients and to gases, so it ads very little to the bulk of the stool.